# How do I prevent an infinite loop when serializing a 3-node reference in Java into JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

In my Spring MVC application I have three classes - Content, Category, and Document - that are all interrelated and must be serialized to JSON, but when doing so cause an infinite loop. The relationship is as such:

```
Content -> List<Category> -> List<Document> -> List<Content> -> (etc.)
```

where Category is a property of Content, etc. I'm trying to serialize it so that the reference ends at List (so that content.categories.documents are exposed to the view), but not finding any way to go about it. Annotating with Jackson's @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference won't work because some of these fields are already annotated as such for other relationships. Not sure how to go about this other than possibly constructing a model specific to the relevant view.

EDIT: If this helps, the error I got was "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)" followed by a trace of the reference chain.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a look at `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation, which can be used for handling cyclic dependencies ([this entry](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_466.html) mentions it)? It won't work for `Collection`s (alas), but does work with POJOs contained in collections, arrays and maps.

Comment: Due to the nature of the relationships, this was going to get a bit too complex. Given more time I may test this theory out further, but business needs pushed me to just build a new resource model.

Comment: Hmmh? Adding an annotation to your 3 classes too complex? It isn't complex when done right, fully declarative.

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` are fairly limited in the types of cycles they can handle. In particular they can only be used to denote parent-child type relationships that are fairly static. In essence, they can only be used to handle hierarchies that are a strict *tree*. But in a vast number of projects object relationships are actually represented by a *graph*, which the two afore-mentioned annotations simply can't handle. The designers of Jackson realized this, and in version 2.0 of the library they introduced a [new mechanism for handling object identity](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity).

With this new mechanism you can annotate all three of your objects (`Content`, `Document` and `Category`) with the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation, and Jackson should then be able to serialize (and deserialize) them properly.

Simple code example:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "someUniquePropertyOfYourClass")
public class Context {
    // fields, constructors, getters/setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using     @JsonIgnore ? It worked better in my case when I was using Hibernate in Spring MVC.

Comment: Can't @JsonIgnore any of the fields because those references are required in other views, e.g. I use document.contents in another view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converters?

Serialize each class individually with converters for other two classes. For example, when serialize Content, write converters for Category and Document. Converts can be identifier for Category and Document. When it comes to deserialization, get objects first and remember their relations. Then rebuild their relations by using identifiers.